# block console output for method call

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am doing something like

```
interface ICalculable
{
    public int Calculate(int input);
}

BigMethod(ICalculable calculable)
{
    Console.Write("Sequence:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int result = calculable.Calculate(i);
        Console.Write($" {i}:{result}");
    }
}
```

Any code running inside of a `ICalculable#Calculate` should not be able to write to the console.

I don't want the `ICalculable` that is passed to `BigMethod` to be able to interrupt `BigMethod`'s console output, even if I pass an instance of

```
class MyCalculable : ICalculable
{
    public int Calculate(int input)
    {
        Console.Write("ruin output");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The output seen at the console should be

```
Sequence: 0:0 1:0 2:0
```

`BigMethod` should somehow be able to mute its call to `Calculate`.

Is there a way to do that?

---

I already thought of using a `StringBuilder` but I want `BigMethod`'s output to be streamable.

Comment: wait a sec, so what to you want to do with `Console.Write("Doctor, please keep touching me ");` ? so you never want it to show?

Comment: @TheGeneral I never want it to show, something inside of `IRunnable#Run` should not be writing to the console

Comment: Looks you want something like `async` or background processing, but then you state that BigMethod's output should not be interrupted?

Comment: if you don't it to show why did you want it be the parameter?

Comment: So does your Run method need to run in its own task, or do you just want to not output from that method?

Comment: @TheGeneral I edited to make it more like how I am using it

Comment: @D-Shih maybe the edit makes it clearer why I'm thinking about this problem. It's also entirely possible I have come up with an approach that's way off the mark and there's a simpler way to get the output I want

Comment: Try [Console.SetOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=netframework-4.8) to redirect the stream

Comment: @JSteward but can't `MyCalculable#Calculate` just set it back?

Comment: @minseong sandboxing is **hard**. If you trying to run rogue code you'd better of to run it in separate process with low permissions/intercepted in/out. Otherwise code can just simply write to console anyway using interop or digging around via reflection...

Comment: What about providing a stream as an argument to `BigMethod` or making it a member of the same class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Console.SetOut`](http://Console.SetOut(TextWriter)%20Method), and [`Console.Out`](http://Console.Out%20Property)

```
public static void Main()
{
   Console.Write("Hello ");

   // current output
   var current = Console.Out;

   // change the output to somewhere else
   Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Stream.Null));

   Run();

   // revert back
   Console.SetOut(current);

   Console.WriteLine("there");
}

private static void Run()
{
   Console.Write("Doctor, please keep touching me ");
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello there
```

However, this seems a little *fishy* / *XY* and prone to outrageously weird results if you are threading.

Comment: yeah I decided to just not do anything and trust users. their problem anyway if stuff goes wrong